# Unable to print json values after parsing in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

The below NodeJS code tries to convert an xml document into json and then parse it.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var parse = require('jsonml').parse;

var jsonML = parse(fs.readFileSync('myfile.xml'));
var jsondata = JSON.parse(jsonML);
console.log(jsondata.BESAPI.Computer[0].ID);
```

It works fine, but I am unable to display the correct values. An error is thrown on the line `console.log(jsondata.BESAPI.Computer[0].ID);`

I am trying to display the ID of each computer in the json object.

Json object

```
{
  "BESAPI": {
    "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "-xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation": "BESAPI.xsd",
    "Computer": [
      {
        "-Resource": "api/computer/2431038",
        "LastReportTime": "Thu, 26 Feb 2015 14:54:41 +0000",
        "ID": "2431038"
      },
      {
        "-Resource": "api/computer/16710075",
        "LastReportTime": "Thu, 26 Feb 2015 14:45:18 +0000",
        "ID": "16710075"
      },
      {
        "-Resource": "api/computer/3415985",
        "LastReportTime": "Thu, 26 Feb 2015 14:50:52 +0000",
        "ID": "3415985"
      }]
      }
}
```

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: How do you know what the json looks like if you can't print it?

Comment: @SLaks I have attached the error message.

Comment: @minseong of-course i tried console.log(jsondata) to know what data it prints.

Comment: @user3846091 So it should print [Object object], not the above json.

Comment: Perhaps he used %j or JSON.stringify...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having your original XML, I can't know for sure what's going on, but [this experiment](http://runnable.com/me/VO-IGvdMB9RS0Eg0) may help you with further investigations.

For an XML like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BESAPI>
  <Computer ID="api/computer/2431038"></Computer>
  <Computer ID="api/computer/16710075"></Computer>
</BESAPI>
```

the output from jsonML looks like this:

```
[ 'BESAPI',                                                                                                           
  [ 'Computer', { ID: 'abc123' } ],                                                                                   
  [ 'Computer', { ID: 'def987' } ] ]
```

which doesn't resemble the JSON you gave us, but attempting to parse it gives the error you presented.

So I'm guessing that the output from jsonML isn't parsable JSON, but a nested array of sorts.